# Clicking on div and appending the value of that div into it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, events

I have some Category Titles that are each being appended into their own div. Clicking on any of the divs opens a modal and **the plan is to append that Category's Title into the modal as well.**

I originally had the title `.append` in a for loop, but each of the category titles was appended next to each other. It must've been due to the loop but moving it out of the loop doesn't load the category divs.

I then inserted an `.eq(i).append` into the statement but it only displayed the first Category Title (in this case it's "Animals").

**Is there a way to append the Category Title into whichever modal it was clicked on?** Would I be able to get the index of that Category Title and append it, similar to what I had originally?

#### JS snippet:

```
let _library,
    _categories;

getCategories(){ 
    return _categories;
}

loadCategories(){
    let categs = _categories

    let htmlElems = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
           htmlElems += "<div class='cat-box cat-num-" + i + "'data-target='#modal-id' data-toggle='modal'>" + categs[i].Title + "</div>";
           $(".modal-title").eq(i).append(categs[i].Title); // ---------- //
      }

     let container = document.querySelector("div.top-training");
     container.innerHTML = htmlElems;
     console.log(container);

}
```

#### index.js:

```
$(document).on("click", '.cat-box', function(val) {
    console.log('.cat-box clicked')
    let cat  = $(this).data('category'),
        desc = $(this).find("span").last().text();

// irrelevant code
```

#### Modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-id" role="dialog">
<!-- ...etc -->
<div class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach to fix this issue.

First, add data attribute `data-title` to the element `.cat-box` to keep title data.

`htmlElems += "<div class='cat-box cat-num-" + i + "'data-target='#modal-id' data-toggle='modal' data-title='"+ categs[i].Title +"'>" + categs[i].Title + "</div>";`

When modal is open read the title data and put inside the `.modal-title` and make it empty on close.

```
$(document).find('#modal-id').off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(document).find('.modal-title').html( $(e.relatedTarget).data('title'));
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(document).find('.modal-title').html('');
});
```

You can see detailed example from [bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

Comment: That did it, thanks! I haven't made as much use of data attributes as I should, and I definitely will in the future.